# Why is PHP prepending a numerical index to my associative array?

Tags: arrays, php-5.5

When I use this code,

```
$views = array();
$views[]=['somevalue'=>'customerview.php'];
$views[]=['anothervalue'=>'ordersview.php'];
```

I get this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [somevalue] => customerview.php
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [anothervalue] => ordersview.php
        )

)
```

How can I make it get rid of the initial array without using array_shift or the like?  Why is it putting the numerical array in the first place instead of just this,

```
Array
(
    [somevalue] => customerview.php
    [anothervalue] => ordersview.php

)
```

EDIT:  How can I use the short syntax for this?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$views[] = ['somevalue' => 'customerview.php'];
```

you're saying, "Push another element onto the array, and assign to it the following value:

```
'somevalue' => 'customerview.php'
```

But this quantity is an array key and an array value. So what you're doing is inserting into your `$views` array a single element that itself contains an array key and array value. This explains the behavior you're seeing.

This should give you the results you want:

```
$views = array();
$views['somevalue'] = 'customerview.php';
$views['anothervalue'] ='ordersview.php';
```

Or, in shorthand:

```
$views = [
   'somevalue' => 'customerview.php',
   'anothervalue' => 'ordersview.php'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can do:

```
    $value1 = 'first';
    $value2 = 'second';

    $array = array(
        $value1 => 'customerview.php',
        $value2 => 'ordersview.php'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`$views` is already an array so when you use `$views[]`, you are adding another array into the existing array.

You need to use

```
$views = array(
    'somevalue' => 'customerview.php',
    'anothervalue' => 'ordersview.php'
)
```